# Using HuggingFace pipeline on pytorch mps device M1 pro

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

i want to run the pipeline abstract for zero-shot-classification task on the mps device. Here is my code

```
pipe = pipeline('zero-shot-classification', device = mps_device)
seq = "i love watching the office show"
labels = ['negative', 'positive']
pipe(seq, labels)
```

The error generated is

```
RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!
```

Which my guess is because seq is on my cpu and not mps. How can i fix this ?
Is there a way to send seq to the mps device so that i can pass it to the pipe for inference?

Thanks

Comment: I am using lower-level primitives (I manually fine-tune models etc.), but I guess, you need to move some tensors to the mps device with `tensor.to()` calls.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Is there any solution?

Comment: "pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", device='mps')" works.

Answer (score 8):

When I had a similar problem, it was fixed by doing `model = model.to("mps")` though that shouldn't have been a problem in your case.

The following code works on my machine:

```py
import os
os.environ["PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK"] = "1"

from transformers import pipeline
mps_device = "mps"
pipe = pipeline('zero-shot-classification', device = mps_device)
seq = "i love watching the office show"
labels = ['negative', 'positive']
pipe(seq, labels)
```